# It is possible to set up domain dns into specific subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, dns

I have question about setting of domains dns. I would like to know if it is possible to set dns of one domain into specific subdomain. For better explanation there is my example: On domain sub.domain.com there is some content which I want to show on domain maindomain.com

It is possible to do this?

Thank you for reply.

Comment: You're looking for name based virtual hosts For apache, check out this documentation: httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts

Comment: If I understand correctly I have to write into .htaccess on maindomain.com something which redirect this domain into subdomain?

Comment: Best would be to set this up in the main server configuration files. Please include some details about the environment

Comment: yes. probably.  the "probably" part depends on the meaning of "some" in "there is some content which I want to show". But dns is the wrong track, apart from setting records for both names to resolve to the same ip address.

Comment: Thank you for reaction but I think that better will be if I tell you what is my goal. If you know tumblr so they first create subdomain for your blog and in administration you just set up dns for own domain and then content from subdomain is redirect into domain. So I would like to create something like this.

Comment: only thing you can use DNS for is to inform client "talk to same interface" or "talk to a different interface"